# Bridgeless totem-pole PFC controllers

Tags: power, integrated-circuit, power-factor-correction, gan, sic

I'm considering bridgeless totem-pole PFC for a design and am looking for the quickest integrated solution. Unfortunately, it seems like a lot of implementations currently use MCUs and DSPs for control of the MOSFET drivers. While it is a a valid solution, it requires additional workload.

This far the integrated options I have found are:

1. NCP1680
2. NCP1681

And possibly ICE3PCS01G in certain configurations. Are there any other upcoming or existing integrated options?

Comment: For your 1-kW TPPFC, you should consider pure CCM operation (not multimode) and not BCM as with 1680.

Comment: I agree, it seems like if it's hard to pass EMI with CCM it will be even worse with CrM,

Comment: @NoobPointerException And even worse with bridgeless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, as of March 2023 few manufacturers offer integrated solutions for bridgeless totem pole PFC.

The three main design choices are:

1. Available integrated solution: NCP1680, NCP1681, IMC102T-F048, MPF32010.
2. MCU/DSP with or without integrated support features. Evaluation designs use circuits like STM32F334, F28004x, UCD3138, TMS320F28335, MC56F83783.
3. Boost PFC circuits in combination with externa logic such as can be seen in EVAL_2500W_PFC_GAN_A.

A good way to choose a design is to view and test available totem pole PFC evaluation boards that many major manufacturers offer.